# Difference in stringstream behavior for void* type using libc++ and libstdc++

Tags: c++, llvm, stringstream, libc++

The following test program returns different results depending on whether I'm using libc++ or libstdc++.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    void* optr = &a;
    void* iptr;

    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << optr;
    std::cout << ss.str() << '\n';

    ss >> iptr;
    std::cout << iptr << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using the following version of clang from Xcode 5 on OSX 10.9.2

```
$ xcrun clang++ --version              
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Here's the output of the test when built with libstdc++ and libc++

```
$ xcrun clang++ test.cpp  <-- libstdc++ version             
$ ./a.out
0x7fff5ec723e8
0x7fff5ec723e8
$ xcrun clang++ test.cpp -stdlib=libc++  <-- libc++ version
$ ./a.out
0x7fff5205125c
0x7fff5
```

Is this a bug in the libc++ implementation of stringstream?  Is this usage of void* with stringstream valid C++?

Thanks!

Comment: [locale.num.get] seems to be the Standard section specifying this. It seems to say that `ss >> iptr` should behave like `sscanf` with `%p` but AFAICS it does not actually specify this. The "Stage 3" description seems to cover the integral and float types, but it overlooks `void *`.  Does `sscanf(ss.str().c_str(), "%p", &iptr);` work?

Comment: @MattMcNabb: I just tested with clang-503.0.38 (based on LLVM 3.4svn), and `sscanf(ss.str().c_str(), "%p", &iptr);` does indeed work for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes! it's a bug in libc++, probably in the implementation of `__sscanf_l` (some `scanf` lookalike that should take locales into consideration). The libstdc++ implemementation is much simpler.

```
// libc++

template <class _CharT, class _InputIterator>
_InputIterator
num_get<_CharT, _InputIterator>::do_get(iter_type __b, iter_type __e,
                                        ios_base& __iob,
                                        ios_base::iostate& __err,
                                        void*& __v) const
{
    // Stage 1
    int __base = 16;
    // Stage 2
    char_type __atoms[26];
    char_type __thousands_sep = 0;
    string __grouping;
    use_facet<ctype<_CharT> >(__iob.getloc()).widen(__num_get_base::__src,
                                                    __num_get_base::__src + 26, __atoms);
    string __buf;
    __buf.resize(__buf.capacity());
    char* __a = &__buf[0];
    char* __a_end = __a;
    unsigned __g[__num_get_base::__num_get_buf_sz];
    unsigned* __g_end = __g;
    unsigned __dc = 0;
    for (; __b != __e; ++__b)
    {
        if (__a_end == __a + __buf.size())
        {
            size_t __tmp = __buf.size();
            __buf.resize(2*__buf.size());
            __buf.resize(__buf.capacity());
            __a = &__buf[0];
            __a_end = __a + __tmp;
        }
        if (this->__stage2_int_loop(*__b, __base, __a, __a_end, __dc,
                                    __thousands_sep, __grouping,
                                    __g, __g_end, __atoms))
            break;
    }
    // Stage 3
    __a[sizeof(__a)-1] = 0;
#ifdef _LIBCPP_LOCALE__L_EXTENSIONS
    if (sscanf_l(__a, _LIBCPP_GET_C_LOCALE, "%p", &__v) != 1)
#else
    if (__sscanf_l(__a, __cloc(), "%p", &__v) != 1)
#endif
        __err = ios_base::failbit;
    // EOF checked
    if (__b == __e)
        __err |= ios_base::eofbit;
    return __b;
}
```

versus

```
// libstdc++

template<typename _CharT, typename _InIter>
_InIter
num_get<_CharT, _InIter>::
do_get(iter_type __beg, iter_type __end, ios_base& __io,
       ios_base::iostate& __err, void*& __v) const
{
  // Prepare for hex formatted input.
  typedef ios_base::fmtflags        fmtflags;
  const fmtflags __fmt = __io.flags();
  __io.flags((__fmt & ~ios_base::basefield) | ios_base::hex);

  typedef __gnu_cxx::__conditional_type<(sizeof(void*)
                     <= sizeof(unsigned long)),
unsigned long, unsigned long long>::__type _UIntPtrType;       

  _UIntPtrType __ul;
  __beg = _M_extract_int(__beg, __end, __io, __err, __ul);

  // Reset from hex formatted input.
  __io.flags(__fmt);

  __v = reinterpret_cast<void*>(__ul);
  return __beg;
}
```

Comment: They both are just as ugly, though. Regardless, this is the first time libstdc++ is simpler than libc++.

Comment: Actually, I think libstdc++'s solution quite beautiful, altough I can't see the reasoning for all those underscores...

Comment: @Massa: [The underscores are there for reserved identifiers for the implementation.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier). It's to make sure that code doesn't conflict with any of your code.

Comment: @Cornstalks Ok, but why underscores in local variables?

Comment: @Massa: Probably because of global variables. On another note, there's got to be some reason why libc++'s is so complex. I should run a benchmark or something...

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: a modern C++ program shouldn't have a lot of global variables (most variables nowadays would be tucked inside namespaces)... the libc++ implementation seems to take locales more into consideration, and it _seems_ to try to solve the various-width-encoding problems I had last year.

Comment: @Massa: That doesn't mean thay every one is that smart. Width-encoding problems!?

Comment: I think the reason why local variables use reserved names too is so that they can't even conflict with macros. In a perfectly conforming implementation, `#define x y` before `#include <vector>` shouldn't break the program.

Comment: @Brian: I don't think this is completely possible (just `#define skipws 1` before `#include <iostream>` and everything goes down the drain), but I understand that it minimizes the damage!

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: until last time I tried, attempts to write anything to a wide-stream or to write a wide-string to a narrower-stream didn't work (and IIRC they should). I am trying again now...

Comment: Thanks to everyone for your comments and suggestions!

Comment: @Massa: Sounds aggravating. Now that I look at it, libc++ does seem to take that into more consideration. On a side note, I remember the time I put `#define std x` before including iostream to see what happened.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos: let me guess... a lot of link errors? :D

Comment: @Massa: Lots. It can be interesting to figure out everything that everything else depends on, however, especially because every single iostream class threw a link error.

Comment: That's because the library symbols are already mangled (in the part of libc++/libstdc++ that is compiled, in .a/.lib or .so/.dll form)... But more interesting are the things that the **language** itself depends like `typeid` (not only depends on the definition of the type `type_info`, but depends on it being on a header called `<typeinfo>`....), `std::initializer_list`, etc...

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in libc++ as of revision 209305.